# tone played by device louder than in code

Tags: android, audio, media-player

Anyone know why android plays back tones on the media player softer than it plays them itself?

For example, my Nexus one plays the tone, pixiedust.ogg when a new email comes in, and its LOUD.  Then, I grabbed the file off the device and play it myself like this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pixiedust);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

This seems to have less than half the volume that it does when the Android system plays it.  Anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
```

On the device, the alarm has one volume control, the application volume a separate control. (I'm assuming they are both set all the way up.)

In addition, you can vary the volume for a particular sound, allowing you to balance different sounds for a particular volume setting if you want to.

Given that, I would assume that the alarm volume automatically increases the base volume for the sound, where as the default MediaPlayer likely has it set to 50% or so by default, so you can fudge it around if desired.